# Strange issue when iterating a STL set<CStudent> in C++

Tags: c++, oop, iterator, getter

I have class `CStudent` and class `CStudentGroup` which has one member `set<CStudent>`. I populate the set of an object from the class `CStudentGroup`. I want to iterate this set and print via the getter of the `CStudent` class the points of all the students in the set. I do this by assigning the set to a new one. Then I iterate the set with an `iterator it`. However the compiler gives an error `*the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function CStudent::getP; object type is const CStudent*` I would like to ask how can I do this? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class CStudent {
    string m_strFN;
    int m_iPoints;
public:
    void setP(int p) {
        m_iPoints = p;
    }
    void setFN(string f) {
        m_strFN = f;
    }
    int getP() {
        return m_iPoints;
    }
    string getFN() {
        return m_strFN;
    }
    CStudent() {
        m_strFN = "123456789";
        m_iPoints = 70;
    }
    CStudent(const CStudent& stud) {
        m_strFN = stud.m_strFN;
        m_iPoints = stud.m_iPoints;
    };
    CStudent(int p) {
        m_iPoints = p;
    }
};
class CStudentGroup {
    set<CStudent> m_setStudents;
public:
    CStudentGroup(const CStudentGroup& grp) {
        m_setStudents = grp.m_setStudents;
    };
    CStudentGroup(set<CStudent> st) {
        m_setStudents = st;
    }
    CStudentGroup() {
        CStudent s1(50), s2, s3(s2);
        m_setStudents.insert(s1);
        m_setStudents.insert(s2);
        m_setStudents.insert(s3);

    }
    set<CStudent> gets() {
        return m_setStudents;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CStudentGroup group;
    set<CStudent> stt = group.gets();
    for (set<CStudent>::iterator it = stt.begin(); it != stt.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->getP() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: [two simple changes to fix this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2983ad34b58fde2)

Comment: I also had to add a comparison operator (required by set)

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` stores keys as constant value, as a change of a key can be a cause of change to its position in red-black tree (typical `std::set` implementation).
In other words, your `CStudent` object are considered `const` or unchangeable.

It's possible to problem here using `std::set::const_iterator` as a type of iterator inside the loop in combination with `std::set::cbegin()` and `std::set::cend()` calls.
Another possible solution is to use `foreach`-loop:

```
for (CStudent const& student : stt)
    std::cout << student.getP() << '\n';
```

Moreover, you would need to change `CStudent::getP()` declaration to be a constant method.

Answer (score 0):

Objects inside a `std::set` are always `const`. That is to protect them, in case you decide you change any key field, the sorting order changes and the set invariant is broken.

So basically the `set<CStudent>::iterator` is a `const_iterator` and you get a `const CStudent&` reference. Since your `CStudent::getP` is not a `const` member function, you cannot use it.

Solution, make it `const`:

```
int getP() const {
    return m_iPoints;
}
```

Naturally, you want to mark as `const` any function that does not change the contents of your object, not only the ones `std::set` requires you to do so. This is sometimes called *const-correctness* and is always a good practice.